# rotates image just once. how to rotate again when selected rotate option multiple times in menu item list?

Tags: android, image, rotation

```
public void Rotate(View v)
{
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),arr[current]);

 // Getting width & height of the given image.
    int w = bmp.getWidth();
    int h = bmp.getHeight();
 // Setting pre rotate to 90
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.preRotate(90);
 // Rotating Bitmap
    Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);
    img.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
}
```

when i select rotate option in menu it only rotates first time when i again select it, image wont rotate. any soln to it

Comment: Which programming language/platform is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, it does rotate your Bitmap each time for 90 degrees. Problem is you always get the same(not rotated) bitmap from the resources, not already rotated from your ImageView.

Instead of:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),arr[current]);
```

Try with this:

```
Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

This solution is also better because you don't decode bitmap from resources each time.

Answer (score 0):

i just used simple Math.

```
public void Rotate_r(View v)
{
    rcount++;
    if(rdgr==360) rdgr=90;
    else rdgr=rdgr+90;
    if(rcount==1){
        ldgr=rdgr;
        rcount--;
    }
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(iv);
    Bitmap bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),arr[current]);
    // Getting width & height of the given image.
    int w = bmp.getWidth();
    int h = bmp.getHeight();
    // Setting pre rotate to 90
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.preRotate(rdgr);
    // Rotating Bitmap
    Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);
    img.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
}
```

i used a counter `rcount` which simply increments if image is rotated right and decrements if it is rotated left. also a variable `rdgr` is initialized to 90 as `rdgr=90` and when `rcount` is incremented it adds 90 more to `rdgr` and plots the image.